# access clicking edit icon in material table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

[image]

I am using Material Table in Reactjs to show the table Data. Here I am stuck at a part where I want to change state  when I click on the edit option/icon. I do not want to change the `onClick` functionality of **Edit** button, but I just want to access edit icon. Is there any way I can achieve it?

Note: I only want it when I click on the edit(pen) icon before it becomes the OK and Cancel buttons.
[image]

Comment: Can you add some code describing your problem ? A more descriptive question will be helpful to understand your problem

Comment: Could you clarify your question what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to remove the default edit button. Then use a `Button` in `action` and `tableRef` props. Now, all you have to do is put the edit's code in `onClick` event like this:

```
var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");
var _objectSpread2 = _interopRequireDefault(
  require("@babel/runtime/helpers/objectSpread")
);
...

export default function MaterialTableDemo() {
  const tableRef = useRef(null);
  ...
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      ...
      tableRef={tableRef}
      actions={[
        {
          onClick: (event, rowData) => {
            console.log("Clicked", rowData);
            tableRef.current.dataManager.changeRowEditing(rowData, "update");

            tableRef.current.setState(
              (0, _objectSpread2["default"])(
                {},
                tableRef.current.dataManager.getRenderState(),
                {
                  showAddRow: false,
                }
              )
            );
          },
        },
      ]}
      ...
    />
  )
}
```

This part is the requirements that material-table uses in it's code:

```
var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");
var _objectSpread2 = _interopRequireDefault(
  require("@babel/runtime/helpers/objectSpread")
);
```

In addition this is the code that you need to fire edit action:

```
tableRef.current.dataManager.changeRowEditing(rowData, "update");
tableRef.current.setState(
  (0, _objectSpread2["default"])(
    {},
    tableRef.current.dataManager.getRenderState(),
    {
      showAddRow: false,
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

If this html template is written by you then you can wrap icon in some parent element and add click event on parent.